# Pandas: how to convert an index of int64 epoc seconds to datetime

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have some timezone information stored in a variable called `tz_pytz` -- I get that form a `hdf5` file along with the dataframe but this is not important right now.

I have an int64 index representing second values since epoch that I want to treat as a timestamp with time zone information:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(h5file['time']).sec
Int64Index([0, ...], dtype='int64')
>>> dt = pd.to_datetime(df, unit='s')
>>> type(dt[0])
pandas.tslib.Timestamp
>>> dt[0].tz is None
True
>>> dt
0    2015-05-29 07:18:22
1    2015-05-29 07:18:23
...
4478   2015-05-29 08:33:06
4479   2015-05-29 08:33:07
Name: sec, Length: 4480, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

This works fine but the data is not time zone aware (`tz is None`). How do I make it time zone aware based on the time zone I have in `py_pytz`?

Comment: what version of pandas and numpy are you using? this works fine in 0.18.1 the problem here is that you're converting an array of ints into a timestamp with no timezone information, so you'd have to add this

Comment: @EdChum: I know it works and has no timezone information. Hence the question. Guess I am unclear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`.tz_localize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.tz_localize.html) to add timezone to your datetime column:

```
In [12]:
df = pd.DataFrame(index=np.arange(10))
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df.index, unit='s')
df['timestamp'] = df['timestamp'].dt.tz_localize('Asia/Hong_Kong')
df['timestamp']

Out[12]:
0   1970-01-01 00:00:00+08:00
1   1970-01-01 00:00:01+08:00
2   1970-01-01 00:00:02+08:00
3   1970-01-01 00:00:03+08:00
4   1970-01-01 00:00:04+08:00
5   1970-01-01 00:00:05+08:00
6   1970-01-01 00:00:06+08:00
7   1970-01-01 00:00:07+08:00
8   1970-01-01 00:00:08+08:00
9   1970-01-01 00:00:09+08:00
Name: timestamp, dtype: datetime64[ns, Asia/Hong_Kong]
```

This will add/remove `tz` information to your timestamp column, it accepts string, `pytz` or `dateutil.tz.tzfile`